# How to ssh between a cluster of Vagrant guest VMs

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

I have 3 Ubuntu 12.04 VMs configured with bridged networking and setup with Vagrant.  I can access all of them from the host using "vagrant ssh", but I can't figure out how I connect from one guest VM to another.

Answer (score 6):

In the Vagrantfile give each of the machines a static private address.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.define "master" do |master|    
        master.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        # You may wish to use a more obscure private ip, like 10.2.2.4
        master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.200"
    end
    config.vm.define "slave" do |slave|    
        slave.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        # You may wish to use a more obscure private ip, like 10.2.2.5
        slave.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.201"
    end
End
```

With these machines both booted you can first ssh into one by name

```
vagrant ssh master
```

And from within this session you can ssh to another machine via its private network ip:

```
ssh 10.0.0.201
```

When prompted for a user/password you can authenticate as `vagrant`/`vagrant`, or further configure an ssh for yourself.

---

This information was adapted from the following post<sup>[1]</sup>:

1. [Vagrant Virtual Machine Cluster](http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/vagrant-virtual-machine-cluster/) Jesse - jessesnet 2014-04-22. Retrieved 2015-02-26

Answer (score 5):

I've just fixed this up in a complex multi CentOS (BoxCutter 6.9) VM Vagrant setup. There are two levels to this problem, my problem was 2:

1. Get your Vagrant config right so that you have a "private_network" and the IP addresses of all your VM's are in the same subnet (static or DHCP):
   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html
2. When ssh'ing between VM's if you get this error:

   `[root@vm01 ~]# ssh root@vm02
   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

   The error message means that none of the authentication methods managed to authenticate your session, and there is no mention of a password option so password authentication has probably been disabled. To fix edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check that you have `PasswordAuthentication yes` and it's not commented out (`#`), then restart `sshd` if required: `service sshd restart` (it won't disconnect any sesssions coz it's clever).

Answer (score 1):

If you have set them up with a bridged interface, it means they all belong to your standard LAN. Thus you can easily access a VM from another VM by issuing

```
 ssh myname@ip_of_vm_2
```

You can find the IPs of your machines either directly from inside each machine, or by using a standard tool like `nmap`, or by asking your router the list of DHCP clients. Lastly, if you know their IP addresses but not their BIOS names, you can use nmbd to associate a name to an IP address:

```
 nmblookup -A IP_address
```

Incidentally, this ease of access (which sets your VMs on the same foot as your LAN pcs) is one of the reason why I always use the bridged interface.

Comment: Thanks. I think the complication comes from the fact that I am trying to bridge using my wireless interface, and wifi adapters (generally? always?) can't be put into promiscuous mode to pick up packets for other addresses.  Is that a possible reason this isn't working?

Comment: No, not true. Bridged configuration on wlan0 works perfectly, I just tried it with VirtualBox, I have three VMs all perfectly connected.